# Update to OneDrive DriveItem FileSystemInfo facet

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to update the FileSystemInfo facet for a DriveItem object in OneDrive but I am running into some unexpected issues.

---

Some background first:

This task is part of Box to OneDrive migration. The users are using a tool for the migration and have noticed once migrated to OneDrive and synced back to their systems the 'created' and 'modified' dates are updated to the date the file was uploaded to OneDrive.

This messes up some of the file management tools they use (multiple files ...same names and now same timestamps) and makes file management difficult.

So we have been asked to update the files with the correct created and modified dates.

From Box developer documentation I see that it has fields to save timestamps for file creation and modify on the client (https://developer.box.com/docs/content-times - specifically the fields content_created_at and content_modified_at).

So the current plan is to use Box API to get the content_created_at and content_modified_at timestamps and then update the filesysteminfo facet of the corresponding file in OneDrive (still trying to workout how to locate that particular file).

---

End of BackGround Info

On trying this out in the Graph developer I can see that filesysteminfo facet createdDateTime and lastModifiedDateTime are updated as expected. However there are two issues:

1. The file in my development system does not show an updated Created and modified date (this works fine if I try to update the filename).
2. I can see that the OneDrive createdDateTime and lastModifiedDateTime also get updated (the ones outside the filesysteminfo facet). This I did not expect.

Could someone guide me on how to get this working and more imp if my understanding is correct

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Hi Jithin, are you calling OneDrive Business or OneDrive Consumer?

Comment: @Brad Hi Brad I am using OneDrive for Business here. I believe I have the solution in hand. I will post whatever I can once I find the time. Thanks.